# Magento 2 urls opening as images

Tags: magento2, url, image, varnish, memcached

I am having this weird issue. Whenever i try to open a product or add them into cart. The link gets opened but as an image.

That is if product link is abc.com/product/123.html

This page only has a body with an img attribute, with src="abc.com/product/123.html"

If i refresh the page, everything is ok, and the product page is loaded fine. but after a few moments i get the same issue again

Using elastic cache (memecached) and varnish

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

I have checked the browser console, getting this issue

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg:
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably could check the .htaccess file in the root directory, or server configs to see if there is something that makes it set the content type to image/jpg.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the Apache `httpd.conf` file and make sure the following AddTypes are included:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
```